# Using boostrap.css file in Rails production/heroku w/o LESS or SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use the glyphicons provided by bootstrap in my rails 4.0beta1 app. Everything works fine in development, but in production nothing gets rendered, and in the heroku logs I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError No Route Matches [GET] "/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png"
```

This is how I'm calling the image file in boostrap.css:

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
 background-image: url("/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png");
}
```

This is how I'm rendering it in the view:

```
<i class="icon-user"></i>
```

When I run rake assets:precompile and start up the production server with rails s -e production, then I can no longer see the icons. I'm not sure why this is the case. I'm not using any gems associated with bootstrap, I just have the plain bootstrap.css file and the image file under assets/images.

**EDIT:**
I also added a .erb extension (bootstrap.css.erb) to use the asset_path helper, but I still only see the icons in development, not production.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, oddly, background-image did not seem to work in production. I was loading other background images using just the background: property, so I tried that and now it (magically) works in production:

```
background: url(<%= asset_path 'glyphicons-halflings.png' %>);
```

with bootstrap.css.erb as the filename.

Still confused as to why background-image was working in development but not production ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple approach:

```
background-image: url('gliphicons-halflings.png')
```

EDIT: glyphicons.scc.scss.erb

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphicons';
src: url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-regular.eot')%>');
src: url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-regular.eot?#iefix')%>') format('embedded-opentype'), url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-regular.woff')%>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-regular.ttf')%>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('glyphicons-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')%>') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

[class^="glyphicons-"]:before {
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Glyphicons';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: inherit;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
```

}

Comment: Just curious, do you use a file `glyphicons.css.scss.erb` in your project? There sould be a definition for `@font-face` about glyphicons.

Comment: Nope, I don't. Just the bootstrap.css file and the glyphicon image files.

Comment: I think you two may be discussing two different versions of bootstrap, with Rumen answering from the perspective of Bootstrap 3.