# Bootstrap date-picker image assets not displaying when deployed (on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using `gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 3.1.3'` to include a date/time-picker in my web app, and it works in development, but when I deploy to Heroku the assets (icons) that the gem uses for up/down arrows and other icons are displaying as empty squares, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Any idea why these are displaying properly?

This is how it should look:

[image]

I am using Rails 4, Ruby 2, and I am deployed on Heroku, thanks!

**UPDATE:** After looking at the Heroku logs, I see this error:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.tttf")`

In my app, I have `"/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-0469longseriesoflettersandnumbers.tttf")`, which is why it's not finding it. What do these letters/numbers mean? Can I safely remove them from the names of the files in Sublime Text? Thanks again

Comment: Did you precompile assets for production?

Comment: Yes, I precompiled assets before deploying. I just re-precompiled and re-deployed, and it still looks the same.

Comment: @Beartech just added some detail if that helps at all, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here [Glyphicon works locally but not on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588786/glyphicon-works-locally-but-not-on-heroku) and here https://holarails.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/problem-twitter-bootstrap-glyphicons-not-show-in-heroku/.

If anyone has a better solution (as it looks like using this can affect performance), I'd appreciate it!